MongoDB ObjectID binding and validation in Golang
I want an use case that receive a list of string (represent for ObjectID hex) and I want to build a struct using binding tag to validate:
If receiving one, we could use:
type SingleID struct {
     PostID primitive.ObjectID json:"post_id" bind:"mongodb" 
}

So if we wanted to received and validated a slice of objectids, do we have any solution likes:
type MultiID struct {
     PostIDs []primitive.ObjectID json:"post_id" bind:"array_mongodb" // or something else 
}

I'm trying to receive a slice of Mongo ObjectIDs from client side, binding and validating by Gin framework
